# Spectrum Spatial Analyst v12 issues on upgrade

Tags: mapinfo, spectrum-spatial-analyst

After I upgraded spectrum ver 11 to 12 and spatial analyst 8 to 12 - my maps open but I don't get the layer control? In the SSA admin console I get a box to choose a color which doesn't go away and all the configs give errors.

Has anyone else tried and seen the same issues -I want to get this running during the weekend and so I can't hitup Pitney Bowes support.

[image]

Spatial Manager
[image]

The map view should look like (this is from our user guide)
[image]

Comment: Can you access the named resources via the Spatial Manager and can Spatial Manager display the named maps and named layers?

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller yes to both. The issue is as per the image in my question. I have added an image of spatial manager.

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you create a new map config in Spectrum Spatial Analyst or is it only for the existing map configs?

Comment: I resolved the issues by copying the xml config files, uninstalling SSA8 and installing 12 and then pasting the old configs back in.